# How to derive this approximation of this definite integral

Tags: integration, approximation

An integral of the form
$$\frac{n_2!}{n_1!}\int_0^{\infty}\mathrm dx\,e^{-x}x^{n_1-n_2}{[L_{n_2}^{n_1-n_2}(x)]}^2f(x),$$
(where $n_1\ge n_2\ge 0$ are integers, $L$ is an associated Laguerre polynomial, and $f$ is a function of the form $f(x)=1/\sqrt{x+a}$, with $a\ge0$) can be approximated at large $n_2$ or large $n_1-n_2$ by the simpler integral
$$\int_0^\pi\frac{\mathrm d\phi}{\pi}f\bigl(n_1+n_2-2\sqrt{n_1n_2}\cos\phi\bigr).$$

I found this approximation in Appendix B of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.04813). However, I have no idea how this approximation was obtained. The mentioned paper doesn't point to any references when it uses this approximation. It mentions that it's called a "semiclassical approximation", but I don't know what that means, and searching online didn't help.

Can you help me derive this approximation? I don't know where to start.

Comment: @JeanMarie Sorry I didn't clarify that $L$ here refers to an associated Laguerre polynomial. I edited the post.

Comment: Is there a connection with "disk line picking" as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2268105) ?